# How is spacetime as a construct defined by philosophers?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, physics

Is spacetime a construct? If spacetime is a construct, is space taken individually a construct, and is time taken individually also a construct, and time and space combined a construct? Does the concept of spacetime understood in physics to be a manifold fusing time and space also include the concept of time and space combined not into a manifold of time and space, but as defined in Newtonian physics? How is the concept exactly defined by philosophers? What are some of the interpretation of this scientifically charged term in philosophy?

Comment: Please post your questions one at a time. and can you define for us exactly what you mean by "construct"?

Comment: Two basic approaches are substantivalism and relationalism, see http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9055/

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question, per se. But I would suggest that the clarity of the question would benefit from engagement with some of the existing literature; I'd suggest checking out the good introductory treatment in The Philosophy of Physics by Dean Rickles, or the Philosophy of Physics: Space and Time by Tim Maudlin (but Rickles first I'd say). There's a more advanced but excellent treatment in World Enough and Spacetime by John Earman. Physicists Sean Carroll and Lee Smolin have both produced popular books (as well as technical papers) on how space and time may be emergent..

Comment: There are notable critics of time being considered a dimension: 'Why Hermann Minkowski was a disaster for physics' https://youtu.be/TDjgQ_megMI

Comment: All of the above are available, when it comes to constructs it is helpful to have ones on hand for any purpose, see [SEP, Absolute and Relational Theories of Space and Motion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/).

Comment: elcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the type of response that you are looking for, but here it is. As a Spinoza author I have conpleted four books and a dozen papers on his system.
To answer your question in a Spinozistic frame would be to characterize time, not as a construct but rather as what he describes as, 'an aid to the imagination'. What this signifies is that time has no meaning outside of human experience. It doesn't make it unreal but consider that time has no meaning in an infinite universe. But it is very relevant to a creature who lives only 60-70 years or so. But our experience of time and seasons and aging, etc. gives us a baseline, so to speak, to reflect on other possibilities, like duration or eternity.
As for space, it too may just be a conceptual aid to our capacity to think beyond the limitations of our existence inside what amounts to a tiny little bubble of oxygen that we term an atmosphere.
What we term space Spinoza terms the Attribute of Extension. This Universal concrete primal expression of eternity cannot be conceived directly by the human mind but can be 'intuited' by the minds-eye.
So as not to go on ad nauseum, I would recommend that you read any introductory work on Spinoza like from Roth or Ruth Saw or Stuart Hampshire or Don Garrett. And go to wikisource and enter "On the Improvement of the Understanding", a 43 page treatise written by Spinoza.
As for physics and it's attribution of objective reality to space time, I tend to think of it as a construct which serves the purpose of allowing for hypothesizing and positing models which allow human minds to theorize and to expand on our very limited real time knowledge of anything outside of our solar system. Cheers and welcome to SEP.

Answer (score 0):

In Newtonian physics, time is not indexed as a dimension; the dimensions here are simply the ordinary three dimensions of space.

Those dimensions are not a "construct", they are an experimental fact, and within the range of applicability of Newton's laws they provide a perfectly adequate stage upon which the dynamics of the universe are played out.

That stage collapses in the presence of very high speeds and extremely large masses or concentrations of energy, and it is in those cases where special and general relativity furnish correct descriptions of reality because they explicitly include time as an extra dimension- although *not* a spatial dimension like the others.

Both special and general relativity were originally purely mathematical constructs which were invented by Einstein without any observational evidence or experimental data to support them. Later, that evidence and data were searched for and found, at which time SR and GR stopped being abstract constructs and were recognized as true representations of the way the universe really works.